# Why can't I multiply two probabilities to find their intersection in this situation?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

What is the probability that a positive integer not exceeding 100 selected at random is divisible by 5 or 7?

I solved it easily using the inclusion-exclusion principle and got $0.32$ as the answer.

However, when multiplying the probabilities of getting a number not divisible by $5$ and the probability of getting a number not divisible by 7, $0.8 \cdot 0.88$ and subtract that from $1$, I get $0.312$, which is incorrect.

The problem seems to be that $0.8 \cdot 0.88$ gives me $0.704$, when the actual probability of getting a number not divisible by $5$ and not divisible by $7$ is $0.684. I don't understand why this happens.
Why can the problem not be solved in this manner?

Comment: Only for independent events can one just multiply probabilities. It must just happen to be your events are not independent. [In this case independence or non independence doesn't seem immediately obvious.]

Comment: 41 is divisible by neither 5 nor 7, so you have accounted for it twice.

Comment: However, notice that they are 'almost independent'.

Comment: Of the $20$ multiples of $5$, only two are also divisible by $7$. That's $\frac 2{20}=.1$ of them.  Of the $100$ total integers, $14$ are divisible by $7$, that's $\frac {14}{100}=.14$ of them.  Thus the events are not independent.

Comment: If you change the problem, so that the positive integer is not to exceed $~35n ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ then the events **are independent**.  The **hidden** point of the problem may be that $~100~$ is not a multiple of $~35. ~$ Alternatively, the problem composer's intent may have simply been to force you to apply Inclusion-Exclusion, which allows you to bypass any consideration of independent events.